# Como parsear un caracter especial UTF-8 a string en c# (\u009e)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un lector de archivos que lee linea por linea lo que tengo en un txt.

Tengo un campo que es "HERNžN" (caracter especial = '\u009e', que sería esta z: ž).

De esta manera leo lo que tengo en el archivo:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f.InputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true))
```

Al momento de pegarle a la base de datos e intentar hacer el insert, me salta el siguiente mensaje de error ERROR: Command parameter[4] '' data value could not be converted for reasons other than sign mismatch or data overflow.

Necesito parsear este caracter o cualquier otro caracter especial que aparezca, de alguna forma a string, alguna idea?

Gracias!

Comment: No recuerdo que ASP.NET sea de Oracle. ¿Puedes ser más claro con el problema? ¿Cómo lo estás cargando?

Comment: ¿Cómo le estás _pegando_ a la base de datos? No es evidente que el Stream quede con el contenido correcto o que la interacción con la BD sea correcta o que la configuración de la instancia de BD permita estos carácteres). Por favor ve a [edit] y añade la info faltante.

Comment: hola @Mateo, mala mia me olvide de agregar el codigo de bd, masomenos seria asi reducido

Comment: `public string funcion(){
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand( "SP_BAJAMASIVA", ConnectionString );
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.Add( "pNOMBRE", OleDbType.VarWChar );
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}`

Comment: [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/578604/edit) la pregunta. Los comentarios no se ven bien si tienen mucho código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de mucho logré encontrar una solución muchas gracias a los que me dieron una mano, dejo mi codigo por si a alguien mas le sucede:
Encontre una funcion que evalua caracter x caracter de un string y verifica si es un "ilegal unicode"->

```
    public bool ilegalUnicode( string str ) {
      for ( int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++ ) {
        var uc = char.GetUnicodeCategory( str, i );
        if ( uc == UnicodeCategory.Control || uc == UnicodeCategory.OtherNotAssigned )
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
```

```
string resultadoParseado = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString( System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( texto );
```